# NAS shared folder with everyone, but only creators of sub-folders must be able to write or delete in that folder, possible?

Tags: permissions, network-shares, shared-folders

we have Windows server with file storage, which is shared as NAS.

We want to create a folder, all users must have access but only user who creates a sub-folder in it, only he/she must be able to write to that folder, rename, delete. No other users must be able to use other's folders.

I'm not sure if it is possible or not but I'm thinking maybe with permissions it can be done. Permissions either pre-configured or users must change it by themselves.

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use `CREATOR OWNER` to give the person who creates a folder the permissions you want (and nobody else). I was writing an answer but couldn't quite get it to work the way I wanted on my home (single user) machine sorry :(

Comment: See [Access Control Lists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-control-lists) and [`icacls`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)